# add_filter on menu items to add a menu item

Tags: menus, filters

I am having some weird issues with adding a function to the filter called 'wp_get_nav_menu_items' . I want this filter code to be triggered after a user logs in, so i put the whole block inside a function attached to an `add_action('wp_login')`  .

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', function ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
// $GLOBALS['myItems'] = $items;
// $GLOBALS['myArgs'] = $args;
write_log_please($menu->slug);
if($menu->slug == "main-menu" && is_user_logged_in() ) {
    write_log_please("THIS MIGHT BE WORKING!");
    $thinkURL = "http://helpgrowusa-academy.thinkific.com/api/sso/v2/sso/jwt?jwt=".$GLOBALS['myJWT']."&return_to=http://academy.helpgrowusa.com";
    $items[6]->url = $thinkURL;
    // write_log_please($items[6]->url);
    write_log_please($items);
    return $items;
}

}, 10, 3);
$trigger = wp_get_nav_menu_items('main-menu');
```

the 'wp_get_nav_menu_items' at the bottom of the code snippet is located in

wp-includes/nav-menu.php .
That function ends with a `return apply_filters('wp_get_nav_menu_items')` . So I add my function to that filter, and then right below I trigger it. I modify $items[6]->url , and then when I log the whole items array i can see that in the 6th index, the url property of that was successfully updated. The 'write_log_please' just logs whatever I want to the error_log , which is wp-content/debug.log . I can see that the source is getting modified correctly. However, this is not reflected in the actual HTML on the page - the url stays the exact same is the original value I gave it in the WordPress admin dashboard for the site. This is very confusing and contradictory, any thoughts? My guess is that first my value is being successfully set, but then the filler-value from the front-end dashboard is overriding this, which is rather annoying if true.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works for me; the menu item is appended to the menu specified by the slug `$args->menu->slug`. I initialized `$GLOBALS['myJWT']` with `xxxxx` for testing.

Comment: I generate a json web token when a user logs in using the wp_login hook. Then, when a person clicks on this button that i am trying to add, that JWT gets injected. That is what $GLOBALS['myJWT'] is for. Then i add this function to the 'wp_nav_menu_items' so i can modify the menu. I use an apply_filter('wp_nav_menu_items') right after my original code to call this function right away. I do that because i want the filter to run after someone logs in. If it runs before it won't have a json web token (ie. the myJWT) to access. So this approach almost certainly won't work for me.